# css3 style for div element implementation like the tags in this website

Tags: html, css, styling

As i'm new to css3, I need help regarding the display of the record. I have implemented an auto complete functionality, when I select the record, It gets stored in the div below. Right now it shows me only the text. Now i want to have styling for the record which should be similar to the Tags in this website. 
Ex: In the Tags section, if we select HTML5 it gets stored like a button with delete image beside it, I need my records to be displayed like that. Give me an idea for styling. Below is the code :

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px;">
<label for="poolName" style=" font-family: serif; font-size:medium;">or start with: </label>
<input id="poolName" name="poolName" type="text" value="" size="60" style="font-family: serif; font-size: small;"  />
</div>

<div  style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: serif; font-size: medium;"> Result: 
<div  id="log"  style="border:1px solid black ; width: 190px; overflow: auto;"></div> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post more information (links, more code) to get a better answer.

P.S. The recommended place for styles are in a <style> tag or separate CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's Developer Tools tells me that the *tag* style is:
`background-color: #E0EAF1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b3cee1;
border-right: 1px solid #b3cee1;
padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 90%;
line-height: 2.4;
white-space: nowrap;`